# Nested groupby in Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to develop an app in Flutter/Dart and I'm stuck on this.

**PROBLEM**:

I'm getting this data from the db :

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "tId":1,
      "langId":1,
      "langName":"English",
      "title":"Title A",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"1a",
            "scontent":"Content A"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1b",
            "scontent":"Content A1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1c",
            "scontent":"Content A2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "tId":1,
      "langId":2,
      "langName":"French",
      "title":"Title (in French) A",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"1a",
            "scontent":"Content French A"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1b",
            "scontent":"Content French A1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1c",
            "scontent":"Content French A2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "tId":1,
      "langId":3,
      "langName":"German",
      "title":"Title (in German) A",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"1a",
            "scontent":"Content German A"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1b",
            "scontent":"Content German A1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"1c",
            "scontent":"Content German A2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "tId":2,
      "langId":1,
      "langName":"English",
      "title":"Title B",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"2a",
            "scontent":"Content B"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2b",
            "scontent":"Content B1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2c",
            "scontent":"Content B2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "tId":2,
      "langId":2,
      "langName":"French",
      "title":"Title (in French) B",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"2a",
            "scontent":"Content French B"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2b",
            "scontent":"Content French B1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2c",
            "scontent":"Content French B2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "tId":2,
      "langId":3,
      "langName":"German",
      "title":"Title (in German) B",
      "bookmark":0,
      "content":[
         {
            "sId":"2a",
            "scontent":"Content German B"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2b",
            "scontent":"Content German B1"
         },
         {
            "sId":"2c",
            "scontent":"Content German B2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Which I'm mapping to this PODO:

```
class ABC {

  int? id;
  int? tId;
  int? langID;
  String? langName;
  String? title;
  List<Content>? content;
  int isBookmark = 0; //0 False | 1 True

  ABC(this.id, this.tId, this.langID, this.langName, this.title, this.content, this.isBookmark);

}

class Content {

 int? sId;
 String? content;

 Content(this.sId, this.content);
 
}
```

I wanted to group by the above data using `tId` which is the same for every content with a different language. I could do this successfully by using `groupBy`:

```
List<ABC>? data = snapshot.data;
var groupByTId = groupBy(
              data, (obj) => (obj as ABC).tId).values.toList();
```

and the data looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "0":[
         {
            "0":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "tId":1,
                  "langId":1,
                  "langName":"English",
                  "title":"Title A",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"1a",
                        "scontent":"Content A"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1b",
                        "scontent":"Content A1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1c",
                        "scontent":"Content A2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "1":[
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "tId":1,
                  "langId":2,
                  "langName":"French",
                  "title":"Title (in French) A",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"1a",
                        "scontent":"Content French A"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1b",
                        "scontent":"Content French A1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1c",
                        "scontent":"Content French A2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "2":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "tId":1,
                  "langId":3,
                  "langName":"German",
                  "title":"Title (in German) A",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"1a",
                        "scontent":"Content German A"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1b",
                        "scontent":"Content German A1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"1c",
                        "scontent":"Content German A2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "1":[
         {
            "0":[
               {
                  "id":4,
                  "tId":2,
                  "langId":1,
                  "langName":"English",
                  "title":"Title B",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"2a",
                        "scontent":"Content B"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2b",
                        "scontent":"Content B1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2c",
                        "scontent":"Content B2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "1":[
               {
                  "id":5,
                  "tId":2,
                  "langId":2,
                  "langName":"French",
                  "title":"Title (in French) B",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"2a",
                        "scontent":"Content French B"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2b",
                        "scontent":"Content French B1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2c",
                        "scontent":"Content French B2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "2":[
               {
                  "id":6,
                  "tId":2,
                  "langId":3,
                  "langName":"German",
                  "title":"Title (in German) B",
                  "bookmark":0,
                  "content":[
                     {
                        "sId":"2a",
                        "scontent":"Content German B"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2b",
                        "scontent":"Content German B1"
                     },
                     {
                        "sId":"2c",
                        "scontent":"Content German B2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now, I want to further `groupby` on the nested class Content using `sId`. I want to merge values of the same `sId` in one object array. But I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried looping through ABC and then groupingBy `sId` but it's not merging all `sId`s in one array.

```
var groupByTId = groupBy(
              data, (obj) => (obj as ABC).tId).values.toList();
          
          for (var objects in groupByTId){
              for (var content in objects){
                var newList = groupBy(content.content!, (Content oj) => oj.sId).values.toList(); <-- doesn't group the data based on sId.
              }
          }
```

Basically, I want data to be in this format:

```
[{
        "1": [{
            "title": "Title A",
            "bookmark": 0,
            "content": [{
                "0": [{
                        "sId": "1a", <-- all 1a's should be together.
                        "scontent": "Content A",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1a",
                        "scontent": "Content French A",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1a",
                        "scontent": "Content German A",

                    }
                ],
                "1": [{
                        "sId": "1b",
                        "scontent": "Content A1",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1b",
                        "scontent": "Content French A1",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1b",
                        "scontent": "Content German A1",

                    }
                ],
                "2": [{
                        "sId": "1c",
                        "scontent": "Content A2",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1c",
                        "scontent": "Content French A2",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "1c",
                        "scontent": "Content German A2",

                    }
                ]
            }]
        }],
    "2": [{
            "title": "Title B",
            "bookmark": 0,
            "content": [{
                "0": [{
                        "sId": "2a",
                        "scontent": "Content B",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2a",
                        "scontent": "Content French B",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2a",
                        "scontent": "Content German B",

                    }
                ],
                "1": [{
                        "sId": "2b",
                        "scontent": "Content B1",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2b",
                        "scontent": "Content French B1",
                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2b",
                        "scontent": "Content German B1",

                    }
                ],
                "2": [{
                        "sId": "2c",
                        "scontent": "Content B2",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2c",
                        "scontent": "Content French B2",

                    },
                    {
                        "sId": "2c",
                        "scontent": "Content German B2",

                    }
                ]
            }]
        }]
}]
```

Would really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Some values in your expected output don't match your initial sample data, can you fix it?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα, I have edited the sample data. Please check.

Comment: You can follow up the `groupBy` with a `map`, which in turn does another `groupBy` on the internal groups.

Comment: @Abion47, can you give an example?

Comment: @Abion47, the first groupBy returned on the Parent class is a Map. How would I do another `groupBy` on the internal group? I tried looping through the map and then doing `groupBy` on the nested class but it doesn't make any difference to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks to perform a nested group on the inner content, but the actual request is to condense the outer group into a single object that aggregates the info of all `ABC` objects that share a `tId` value. What's more, the example of resulting data somewhat arbitrarily chooses a value for `title` and `bookmark` and drops `id`, `langId`, and `langName` entirely. As such, your request is given in a way that will invariably result in solutions that involve a certain level of guesswork and arbitrariness.

Another issue is that, since you are fundamentally altering the structure of the `ABC` object after the second "grouping", the POGO you posted will no longer work for the resulting structure. This solution will then require an entirely new POGO to be generated to accommodate the new structure.

As such, here is a potential solution. Note that, since `groupBy` is not a function that is part of the standard Dart library and you don't specify what package you are using for it, I will be using my own [`darq`](https://pub.dev/packages/darq) library for this functionality.

---

Main Logic:

```dart
import 'package:darq/darq.dart';

void main() {
  // Deserialize data into POGOs
  final abcs = data.map((d) => ABC.fromMap(d)).toList();

  // Group by tId
  final grouped = abcs.groupBy((d) => d.tId); 
  
  // Aggregate the previous groups
  final collapsed = grouped.map(
    (g) => g.fold(<int, ABCPacked>{}, (Map<int, ABCPacked> map, ABC abc) {
      // Create the aggregate packed ABC object that subsequent
      // ABCs will dump their data into.
      if (!map.containsKey(abc.tId)) {
        map[abc.tId] = ABCPacked(
          abc.tId,
          abc.title,
          abc.isBookmark,
        );
      }
      final packedContent = map[abc.tId]!;
      // Loop through the content of the ABC object and sort
      // it into the resulting packed ABC based on sId
      abc.content.forEach((Content content) {
        if (!packedContent.content.containsKey(content.sId)) {
          packedContent.content[content.sId] = <Content>[];
        }
        packedContent.content[content.sId]?.add(content);
      });
      return map;
    }),
  );
}
```

---

Incoming Data POGOs:

```dart
class ABC {
  final int id;
  final int tId;
  final int langID;
  final String langName;
  final String title;
  final bool isBookmark; // The database may treat this like an int, but there's no reason to keep it as one
  final List<Content> content;

  ABC(this.id, this.tId, this.langID, this.langName, this.title, this.isBookmark, this.content);

  factory ABC.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    assert(map.containsKey('id') && map['id']! is int);
    assert(map.containsKey('tId') && map['tId']! is int);
    assert(map.containsKey('langId') && map['langId']! is int);
    assert(map.containsKey('langName') && map['langName']! is String);
    assert(map.containsKey('title') && map['title']! is String);
    assert(map.containsKey('bookmark') && map['bookmark']! is int);
    assert(map.containsKey('content') && map['content']! is List);

    final content = (map['content']! as List<dynamic>).map((c) => Content.fromMap(c));
    return ABC(
      map['id']!,
      map['tId']!,
      map['langId']!,
      map['langName']!,
      map['title']!,
      map['bookmark']! == 1,
      content.toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ABC {id: $id, tId: $tId, langID: $langID, langName: $langName, title: $title, isBookmark: $isBookmark, content: $content}';
  }
}

class Content {
  final String sId; // int doesn't match the type from the source data
  final String content;

  Content(this.sId, this.content);
 
  factory Content.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    assert(map.containsKey('sId') && map['sId']! is String);
    assert(map.containsKey('scontent') && map['scontent']! is String);

    return Content(map['sId'], map['scontent']);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Content {sId: $sId, content: $content}';
  }
}
```

---

New Resulting Data POGO:

```dart
class ABCPacked {
  final int tId;
  final String title;
  final bool isBookmark;
  final Map<String, List<Content>> content = {};

  ABCPacked(this.tId, this.title, this.isBookmark);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ABCPacked {tId: $tId, title: $title, isBookmark: $isBookmark, content: $content}';
  }
}
```

---

Resulting Data Structure:

```
{
  1: ABCPacked {
    tId: 1, 
    title: Title A, 
    isBookmark: false, 
    content: {
      1a: [
        Content {sId: 1a, content: Content A}, 
        Content {sId: 1a, content: Content French A}, 
        Content {sId: 1a, content: Content German A}
      ], 
      1b: [
        Content {sId: 1b, content: Content A1}, 
        Content {sId: 1b, content: Content French A1}, 
        Content {sId: 1b, content: Content German A1}
      ], 1c: [
        Content {sId: 1c, content: Content A2}, 
        Content {sId: 1c, content: Content French A2}, 
        Content {sId: 1c, content: Content German A2}
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  2: ABCPacked {
    tId: 2, 
    title: Title B, 
    isBookmark: false, 
    content: {
      2a: [
        Content {sId: 2a, content: Content B}, 
        Content {sId: 2a, content: Content French B}, 
        Content {sId: 2a, content: Content German B}
      ], 
      2b: [
        Content {sId: 2b, content: Content B1}, 
        Content {sId: 2b, content: Content French B1}, 
        Content {sId: 2b, content: Content German B1}
      ], 
      2c: [
        Content {sId: 2c, content: Content B2}, 
        Content {sId: 2c, content: Content French B2}, 
        Content {sId: 2c, content: Content German B2}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that the way this approach chooses which value to use for a given `ABC`'s `title` and `isBookmark` value is to just use the first value it finds when creating the resulting `ABCPacked`. This approach assumes that the values you get from your database will be in order with your desired values at the top, which I cannot guarantee will be the case. If you wish to employ some alternate logic to choose these values, you will need to alter this solution accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant reply! This works so well especially the nested grouping except for a small problem. I was using `package:collection/collection.dart`  to `groupby` by `tId` in initial code. However, when using your package `darq.dart`, it is not grouping together the first 7 values. I have taken a screenshot here: https://snipboard.io/G23d8T.jpg  As you can see, using `darq.dart`, it shows 7 values extra (total: 247) compared to using `collection.dart` package (240 values). Would you happen to know why this is happening? This is second screenshot: https://snipboard.io/pDPRrI.jpg

Comment: @input That is curious indeed. Are you using this same data structure for this test? (Seeing as the size of the map is ~250, it's unlikely.)

Comment: thank you for responding. Yes I'm using the same data structure as posted above. I'm getting the data from the database which is then mapped to the above POJO. I have used custom `groupBy` extensions and they group correctly just like the `groupBy` from the `collection` package. However, this strange occurrence is only with `darq`. Anyhow for now I've decided to stick with `collection` package and tweaked the above solution to work with it. So thank you regardless. :)

Comment: @input Does your output from either your `darq` or your `collection` approach match the output I posted under "Resulting Data Structure"?

Comment: yes the output matches with the `collection` package. For `darq`, it (the outer/first list) matches only after the 7th object in the list. Once the parent list is groupedBy correctly (in case of `darq` after 7th), the child list groups perfectly like the above code.

Comment: @input That's strange as I produced the "Resulting Data Structure" using the above code that used `darq`. I'm not sure what's going on there, then.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is bad set out, according to your expected output you are trying to group by `tId` and `sId`, moreover you are not returned the right values for other fields, the structure for your output is bad arranged, IMHO.

```
// @dart=2.13
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:_samples2/data/data4.dart';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

extension on List<JMap> {
  List<JMap> groupBy(List<String> fields) {
    if (fields.isNotEmpty && fields.length <= length) {
      if (every((m) => m.keys.toSet().intersection(fields.toSet()).length == fields.length)) {
        var result = <String, List<JMap>>{};
        forEach((m) {
          var key = jsonEncode(fields.map((k) => m[k]).toList());
          fields.forEach((k) => m.remove(k));
          result.containsKey(key)
            ? result[key]!.add(m)
            : result[key] = [m];
        });
        
        return result.entries.map((me) {
          var values = jsonDecode(me.key) as List;
          return JMap.fromEntries(List.generate(fields.length, (i) => MapEntry(fields[i], values[i]))..add(MapEntry('group', me.value)));
        }).toList();
      }
      throw "ERROR: Some items from list don't contain the field name(s) specified.";
    }
    throw 'ERROR: You need to input one valid field name al least.';
  }
}


class AnyServer {
  static List fetchData() => jsonDecode(data_raw);

  static List<JMap> getNormalizedData() {
    final data = fetchData();
    var content = <JMap>[];

    data.forEach((m1) { 
      ((m1 as JMap)['content'] as List).forEach((m2) {
        content.add((m2 as JMap)..addAll({
          'langId' : m1['langId'],
          'langName' : m1['langName'],
          'id' : m1['id'],
          'tId' : m1['tId'],
          'title' : m1['title'],
          'bookmark' : m1['bookmark'],
        }));
      });
    });
    return content;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  print(AnyServer.getNormalizedData().groupBy(['tId', 'sId']));
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {tId: 1, sId: 1a, group: [{scontent: Content A, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 1, title: Title A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French A, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 2, title: Title (in French) A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German A, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 3, title: Title (in German) A, bookmark: 0}]}, 
  {tId: 1, sId: 1b, group: [{scontent: Content A1, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 1, title: Title A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French A1, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 2, title: Title (in French) A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German A1, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 3, title: Title (in German) A, bookmark: 0}]}, 
  {tId: 1, sId: 1c, group: [{scontent: Content A2, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 1, title: Title A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French A2, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 2, title: Title (in French) A, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German A2, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 3, title: Title (in German) A, bookmark: 0}]}, 
  {tId: 2, sId: 2a, group: [{scontent: Content B, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 4, title: Title B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French B, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 5, title: Title (in French) B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German B, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 6, title: Title (in German) B, bookmark: 0}]}, 
  {tId: 2, sId: 2b, group: [{scontent: Content B1, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 4, title: Title B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French B1, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 5, title: Title (in French) B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German B1, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 6, title: Title (in German) B, bookmark: 0}]}, 
  {tId: 2, sId: 2c, group: [{scontent: Content B2, langId: 1, langName: English, id: 4, title: Title B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content French B2, langId: 2, langName: French, id: 5, title: Title (in French) B, bookmark: 0}, {scontent: Content German B2, langId: 3, langName: German, id: 6, title: Title (in German) B, bookmark: 0}]}
]
```

### Edit (May 25)

I've added these two functions:

```
extension on List<JMap> {
....
  List<T> getField<T>(String field, {bool distinct = false}) {
    if (every((m) => m.containsKey(field))) {
      var list = map<T>((m) => m[field]);
      return distinct ? list.toSet().toList() : list.toList();
    }
    return [];
  }
}

class AnyServer {
...
  static List<JMap> formatGroupedData(List<JMap> data) {
    var list = data.getField<int>('tId', distinct: true);
    var neo = [Map.fromEntries(List.generate(list.length, (i) => MapEntry(list[i].toString(), [{}])))];

    var i = 0;
    neo[0].forEach((k, v) {
      late String key;
      var ik = int.parse(k);

      key = 'title';    v[0][key] = data[i]['group'][0][key];
      key = 'bookmark'; v[0][key] = data[i]['group'][0][key];
      v[0]['content'] = [{}];
      
      var j = 0;
      while (i < data.length && data[i]['tId'] == ik) {
        v[0]['content'][0][j.toString()] = <JMap>[];
        List<JMap> item = v[0]['content'][0][j.toString()];
        (data[i]['group'] as List).forEach((m) {
          m = m as JMap;
          item.add({
            'sId': data[i]['sId'],
            'scontent': m['scontent'],
            'langId': m['langId'],
            'langName': m['langName'],
          });
        });
        j++;
        i++;
      }
    });
    return neo;
  }
}
```

Running the program with:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print(AnyServer.formatGroupedData(AnyServer.getNormalizedData().groupBy(['tId', 'sId'])));
}
```

You get:

```
[
  {
    1: [
      {
        title: Title A, 
        bookmark: 0, 
        content: [
          {
            0: [
              {sId: 1a, scontent: Content A, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 1a, scontent: Content French A, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 1a, scontent: Content German A, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ], 
            1: [
              {sId: 1b, scontent: Content A1, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 1b, scontent: Content French A1, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 1b, scontent: Content German A1, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ], 
            2: [
              {sId: 1c, scontent: Content A2, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 1c, scontent: Content French A2, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 1c, scontent: Content German A2, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ], 
    2: [
      {
        title: Title B, 
        bookmark: 0, 
        content: [
          {
            0: [
              {sId: 2a, scontent: Content B, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 2a, scontent: Content French B, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 2a, scontent: Content German B, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ], 
            1: [
              {sId: 2b, scontent: Content B1, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 2b, scontent: Content French B1, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 2b, scontent: Content German B1, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ], 
            2: [
              {sId: 2c, scontent: Content B2, langId: 1, langName: English}, 
              {sId: 2c, scontent: Content French B2, langId: 2, langName: French}, 
              {sId: 2c, scontent: Content German B2, langId: 3, langName: German}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now you can use your classes or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the latest Dart and this code is throwing too many errors. Starting with `typedef`, it's throwing this error: `Invalid generic function type.  Try using a generic function type (returnType 'Function(' parameters ')`

Comment: Then you are not using latest version of Dart, which is 2.13, update your system please

Comment: I updated to Dart 2.13 and now I'm getting the error: `type 'ABC' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`. I'm mapping the database output to the ABC and Content PODO object and it's throwing this error.

Comment: That is not a problem of Dart version but your casting, `ABC` is a class and `JMap` or `Map<String, dynamic>` is a Map, your class needs a constructor like `ABC.fromJson(JMAP data)` and to likely modify the structure of your class if you are using the result of my code. If you don't wanna work with 2.13 you can delete the line where `typedef` is used and change every `JMap` with `Map<String, dynamic>`, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I have tried to make this work, but unfortunately I cannot get the output I want. Is there any other solution without changing the structure of the class? I have removed the extra values from the sample output if it makes it easier. I just need to know how to group the nested content list based on specific key value which is `sId`.

Comment: I already have a constructor `ABC.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)`. This is how I'm getting the data from the DB: `Future<List<ABC>> getABCData(int catID) async {
    final Database db = await database;

    var res = await db.query("abc",
        where: "langID IN (1,2) and catID = ?",
        whereArgs: [catID]);

    List<ABC> list =
      res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => ABC.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];

    return list;
  }`

Comment: Bro, you really are lacking some programming skills like analysis, have you tried to understand my code? Because you needed to format its output only and the job was done. I've modified my answer above.